# Flutter Local Notifications Custom Sound

Tags: flutter, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I added custom sound with 3 to 4 seconds it works fine, but when I add a long sound with one minute or more it works on emulator but it doesn't work on real device, like azan sound, I added an azan sound but it doesn't work(I mean the sound does not work, but the notification works fine but it only vibrates), does anyone face this issue? or added a long sound and worked?

here is my notification code, it works perfectly on the emulator, but it doesn't work on real device, tested with Xiaomi 11T, Huawei Mate 10 Lite, Honor X7,

```
await localNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
    id,
    title,
    body,
    tz.TZDateTime.from(date, tz.local),
    NotificationDetails(
      android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
        sound,
        'High Importance Notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Channel Desc',
        color: Colors.green,
        playSound: true,
        priority: Priority.max,
        sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound(sound),
        importance: Importance.max,
        enableVibration: true,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        // styleInformation: BigTextStyleInformation(body),
      ),
      iOS: const DarwinNotificationDetails(
        presentAlert: true,
        presentBadge: true,
        presentSound: true,
        sound: 'sound.wav',
      ),
    ),
    uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
        UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
    payload: jsonEncode({
      'title': title,
      'id': '$id',
    }),
  );
  await localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
    const InitializationSettings(
      android: AndroidInitializationSettings(
        '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
      ),
      iOS: DarwinInitializationSettings(),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved by adding keep.xml inside raw folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).